# mysql sum is not working properly

Tags: mysql

This is my select query i am try to fetch moldNo from moldmaster if there is more than one record of same designMasterId than it is automatically sum of that moldno but problem is when i am trying to fetch moldNo than result shows me double moldno

example : 4 + 3 answer is 14

```
SELECT designMaster.designMasterId,dNo,dWet,nextProcess,itemnm,SUM(moldNo) AS moldNo
                                 ,mold,status
                     FROM   designMaster
                    JOIN item ON item.itemId = designMaster.itemId
                    JOIN process ON process.designMasterId = designMaster.designMasterId
                    JOIN moldmaster ON moldmaster.designMasterId = designMaster.designMasterId
                    GROUP BY designMaster.designMasterId
                    ORDER BY designMaster.designMasterId
```

Comment: could you show your data sample? or sqlfiddle if possible? we even't can't see where that moldno comes from? from which table? :-)

Comment: which field u want to see? @Alex

Comment: fields of moldMaster table (1)moldmaster(2)designMasterId(3)mold(4)moldNo

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT designMaster.designMasterId,dNo,dWet,nextProcess,itemnm,SUM(moldNo) AS moldNo
                             ,mold,status
                FROM   designMaster
                JOIN item ON item.itemId = designMaster.itemId
                JOIN process ON process.designMasterId = designMaster.designMasterId
                JOIN moldmaster ON moldmaster.designMasterId = designMaster.designMasterId
                GROUP BY designMaster.designMasterId,dNo,dWet,nextProcess,itemnm,mold,status
                ORDER BY designMaster.designMasterId
```

Comment: when designMasterId is same it is sum of that moldno. but through that query it's not working.. @Ankit Bajpai

Comment: Which 1 yours or mine.

Comment: my query maybe there is maybe some problem in my query,maybe joining is not perfect in my old query

Answer (score 0):

this is my select query thought that i get excet output.

```
SELECT designMaster.designMasterId,dNo,dWet,nextProcess,itemnm,SUM(moldNo) AS moldNo
                                 ,mold,status,processNm
                     FROM   designMaster,item,moldmaster,processmaster,process
                     WHERE  item.itemId = designMaster.itemId
                     AND   process.designMasterId = designMaster.designMasterId
                     AND  moldmaster.designMasterId = designMaster.designMasterId
                     AND  processmaster.processMasterId = designMaster.nextProcess
                    GROUP BY designMaster.designMasterId
                    ORDER BY designMaster.designMasterId
```